# Removing the border of a button when hovered over or clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I remove the border of this button? It's not a custom button - it just has an image.

[image]

Comment: I don't see a border in the linked image. Not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: The light grey part around the image. That only appears when it is hovered over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button's `FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor` to transparent, either via the properties panel at design time, or at runtime:

```
button1.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

While you're at it, you may also want to change the color when the button is being clicked too:

```
button1.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

However, it's not going to give the user much indication of being a button anymore.

Comment: gah beat me to the punch :P